# I get null value in future

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:upi_pay/upi_pay.dart';

class Homes extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_HomesState createState() => _HomesState();
 }

class _HomesState extends State<Homes> {
@override
 void initState() {
 print('hai im from initial');
 payment();
 super.initState();
 }

 Future<List<ApplicationMeta>> payment() async {
   final List<ApplicationMeta> appMetaList =
      await UpiPay.getInstalledUpiApplications();

   return appMetaList;
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   payment().then((value) => print(value));
    return Container();
 }
 }
```

I get a null value. I think the null value because of the future but I cannot find where I make mistake. This program is about print all installed upi applications.

Comment: Use `FutureBuilder` widget for future handling inside of a build method.

Comment: FutureBuilder<List<ApplicationMeta>>(
        future: payment(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, t) {
          if (t.hasData) {
            print(t.data);
          }
          return Container();
        });   This is my future builder again it returns null. I knew Its wrong But i don't know how to rewrite. Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class _HomesState extends State<Homes> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        print('hai im from initial');
        //payment(); // no need to call it here as simple funcation.
        super.initState();
      }

      Future<List<ApplicationMeta>> payment() async {
        final List<ApplicationMeta> appMetaList =
          await UpiPay.getInstalledUpiApplications();

        return appMetaList;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // payment().then((value) => print(value));
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: payment(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            //check if connection state is done
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) print('loaded ${snapshot.data}');
            print(snapshot.connectionState);
          });
        }
      }
```